# How can I create a counter until a certain number is reached

Tags: java, panel

How can I create a program that reaches a certain number? I'm creating a flag using JPanels but i need to keep going until I reach 350000. This means having to change each number accordingly in each line. I want to create a program which gives me the numbers in the JPanel and setbackground line up until 350000. Also in the panes.

so far (only 4);

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Albania {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame albania = new JFrame();
    albania.setTitle("Albania");
    albania.setSize(300, 200);
    albania.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setBackground(Color.red);
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel2.setBackground(Color.red);
    JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
    panel3.setBackground(Color.red);
    JPanel panel4 = new JPanel();
    panel4.setBackground(Color.red);
    Container pane = albania.getContentPane();
    pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));;
    pane.add(panel1);
    pane.add(panel2);
    pane.add(panel3);
    pane.add(panel4);
    albania.setVisible(true);

}
```

}

Comment: Use a loop? But you might run out of memory with that many panels.

Comment: Just use a loop....

Comment: <Sings "350000 JPanels Hanging On The Wall">

Answer (score 1):

The answer for what you have asked is add panels in a loop

```
     JFrame albania = new JFrame();
        albania.setTitle("Albania");
        albania.setSize(300, 200);
        albania.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       Container pane = albania.getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));;

for(int i =0; i < 350000; i++){
     JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setBackground(Color.red);
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
     pane.add(panel1);
    }
        albania.setVisible(true);
```

if you only objective is create a colored grid, you should use JLabels instead of JPanels... JPanel is a more complex object and leading with so many concurrent instances of it will lead you to bad performance in your application

Answer (score 0):

This creates an ArrayList of 350,000 JPanel objects and adds them to your JFrame.  As the commenter noted above, this is likely going to cause very poor performance if there is even enough memory to complete the operations.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame albania = new JFrame();
    ArrayList<JPanel> panels = new ArrayList<>();
    albania.setTitle("Albania");
    albania.setSize(300, 200);
    albania.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel newPanel;
    for (int x = 0; x<350000; x++) {
        newPanel = new JPanel();
        newPanel.setBackGround(Color.red);
        panels.add(new JPanel());
    }

    Container pane = albania.getContentPane();
    pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));

    for (int x = 0; x<350000; x++) {
        pane.add(panels.get(x));
    }
    albania.setVisible(true);

}
```

Comment: why 2 loops? you could do it with only one

Comment: I was following the structure of his code, you are correct.  I upvoted your answer for it.

Answer (score 0):

Like the others have suggested, a for loop is needed.  However, you may need to access one of the 350,000 JPanels again.  Although this will take up much memory, make an array.

```
’JFrame albania = new JFrame();
    albania.setTitle("Albania");
    albania.setSize(300, 200);
albania.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   Container pane = albania.getContentPane();
    pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
 JPanel[] panels = new JPanel()[350000];
 for(int i =0; i < 350000; i++){
 panels[i] = new JPanel();
     panels[i]setBackground(Color.red);
 pane.add(panels[i]);
}
    albania.setVisible(true)`
```